# Tasker - To switch between Wifi and Mobile Data

Tags: wi-fi, tasker, mobile-data

Can Tasker be programmer to do a one click:
1. Turn off Wifi and turn on Mobile Data
2. Turn off Mobile Data and then Turn On Wifi

I want something that's quick, one click to switch to WIFI only or Mobile Only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dstackoverflow) (free):

1. [Wi-Fi set state block](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/wifi_set_state.html)
2. [Mobile data set state block](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/mobile_data_set_state.html) (rooted device required)

Comment: no way to switch on data from non-rooted device?

Comment: @rvpals Unlikely. Maybe using the "svc data enable" shell command.